# How to import material icons as SVG?

Tags: css, angular, google-material-icons

I am currently creating an icon component in Angular. For this purpose, I am importing the material-icons library inside my css-file:

`@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons");`

Now I have access to material icons, I can simply use them with the known syntax, e.g.:

`<span class="material-icons">home</span>`

All of this works fine as long as the size of my icons equals 24px. However, when resizing the icons, they appear blurry.

I was thinking that material icons are SVGs, and it says on [this](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/) website that they are available as SVGs. Apparently, I have imported the PNGs and not the SVGs. Is there a way to import the SVGs using a CDN such as the Google fonts I have imported?

Comment: A font like you're using could be just a cdn, whereas SVG being individual files requires [a little more setup work](https://blog.shhdharmen.me/material-design-icons-font-vs-svg-and-how-to-use-svg-sprites-in-angular) so the answer is no you can't just plop a cdn link in there and have them work, but you can integrate them and use them another way if you wish.

Comment: ok, thx a lot, Chris! ... even when increasing my font-size from 24px to 32px, which is still a standard size, my icons become blurry. Why would this happen? It seems that material icons font-size specifies the width and the height of the icon. I would expect that it describes only the height, since scaling if the icon is not quadratic will result in blurring the icon.

Comment: class "material icons" if a font. You can try some like `<span style="font-size:31px" class="material-icons">home</span>` -use a **odd** value of pixels-